# Stop UIView being dragged around screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, phonegap-plugins

We are integrating a third party offer wall into our iOS phonegap app.

When we show the offerwall it gets added to the standard phonegap viewcontroller and shows over the top of our webview.

The problem with it is that people can drag the view all over the place so instead of just scrolling up and down in place. Which gives the effect show in the screenshot below:

[image: View being dragged off screen]

What we want to achieve is being able to anchor this view so it can't be dragged around the app and can only be scrolled vertically.

In the integration code we have access to a UIView for the offerwall and the ViewController of the main app.

The offerwall is provided as a library so I don't have access to any of its code and can only deal with the UIView returned and the UIViewController I add it to. Other apps have managed to implement the view without horizontal scrolling

We are looking for code to apply to either the UIView or ViewController to prevent this.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of view is the offer wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was quite simple. Turns out the offerwall was a UIWebView and in testing mode the offerwall page was rendering some elements that were overflowing the page hence the horizontal scrolling. In production mode the problem goes away

Answer (score 1):

The offerwall view probably contains a `UIScrollView` that holds the actual content.  You could try looping through all subviews and turn off scrolling on the first scroll view it finds:

```
    for (UIView *view in offerwall.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView*)view;

            scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            return;
        }
    }
```

This is definitely hacky, but if you don't have access to anything else from their code it might be your only option.